# Update a prop in a child component after an event in parent component?

Tags: reactjs

Take 2 components:

ParentComponent
ChildComponent

ParentComponent sets up ChildComponent within render:

```
render() {
    return (
        <ChildComponent x='default value' />
    )
}
```

Then, ParentComponent wants to change x='default value' to 'hello', maybe in response to an onClick event.

My confusion I think is, I know how to set up the initial variable x, but not how to change it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage this in `Parent` state and then pass the state value as a prop to `Child`.

Child Component.

```
const ChildComponent = props => {
   return <div>{props.x}</div>;
};
```

Parent Component

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       x: "default value"
    };
}

changeX = x => {
   this.setState({
      x: x
   });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
     <ChildComponent x={this.state.x} />
     <button
        onClick={() => {
          this.changeX("x");
       }}
     >
       Change X
     </button>
    </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-wjpcn).

Answer (score 1):

Lift your state up to your `Parent` and pass it to `Child` via `props`

```
const Parent = () =>{
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('foo')

    return(
        <>
            <Child title={title} />
            <button onClick={() => setTitle('bar')}>Change to bar</button>
        </>
    )
}

const Child = ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>
```

For `class` based components

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = { title: 'foo' }

    render() {
        const { title } = this.state
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({ title: 'bar' })}>Change to bar</button>
                <Child title={title} />
            </>
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { title } = this.props
        return <div>{title}</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the state will be shared to many child components, then the term lifting state up is applicable. Otherwise, it's just passing state as props. you think so?

Comment: Lift the state means exactly that. To lift the state to a higher position in the components tree. You just need a hierarchy relationship to  be a valid term